# How do I handle unescaped MySQL data in a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql

**Background:**

1. User submits the following data `firstName`
2. I escape user's data using `mysql_real_escape_string` and store it in MySQL memory table (`table1`).
3. A PHP cron runs every 5 minutes then SELECTS this data into a PHP array (for replication reasons) and executes the following INSERT command to an identical table but in InnoDB format (`table2`):

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`,`firstName`) VALUES ('1','aaa');
```

**Problem:**

If a user sends data with a single quote `'`, i.e, "John's", it is escaped WHILE saving, but not saved escaped. Meaning, it's saved with the single quote into `firstName` of `table1`.

When the above insert command takes place, the unescaped data breaks the whole insert command. How do I deal with this without manually escaping at every juncture?

I can't shift to PDO or mysqli at the moment.

Comment: Unescaped data should not break `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Comment: Escaping is only necessary for literals in the SQL query. That `INSERT` just copies the data internally within the database.

Comment: Apologies, updated the query that breaks it.

Comment: Try again. There's no user data in the new `INSERT` command, and nothing that needs escaping.

Comment: For replication reasons, I have to first read from table1 into an array and then write it back to table2. In this process, unescaped data that is stored in table1 finds it's way into the insert query.

Comment: So… escape the data again like every other user provided input, before using it in your insert query?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without me having to escape it again? From MySQL perhaps?

Comment: Not if you're creating literals in a SQL query.

Comment: You just need to understand that escaping is not in stored data, it's just necessary for parsing the SQL query string.

Comment: @Reddox Can you please provide a fuller example, specifying the different parts?  Where and when is data initially inserted?  What does the cron do?  Don't paraphrase.

Comment: @mrjink updated with a clear scenario. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Barmar I get that.. Question is how I can prevent my subsequent insert queries from crashing without manually escaping the select queries.

Comment: @Reddox Please see [knittl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21301776/2020834).

Comment: You have to call `mysql_real_escape_string` again.

Comment: Have you considered using `mysqldump` instead of your own PHP script to replicate the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot avoid this without manually escaping data everytime you use it in a literal SQL query. Either use parametrized statements or escape your data.

What do you mean with your "replication reasons"? Maybe you don't need to fetch all data from your database, just so you can push it back into another table. Inserting directly from another table is much more efficient.

Comment: I think he means he's replicating to a different server.